# Spring: Inject URL for classpath resource

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject the URL of a classpath resource in a way that does not create a dependency on Spring in the Bean. Meaning, the bean should not use Spring's interfaces/classes. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "URL", exactly? This is a rather artificial concept with classpath resources - what would you do with that URL?

Comment: open a stream and read from it

Comment: If it's a classpath resource, why not just inject the path itself? There's little value in Spring resource abstraction if you're not going to use it.

Comment: @skaffman because it located through the classpath which means through the classloader used by the bean factory which is not the same as the classloader of the bean using the path (due to delegation)

Comment: If you say so. I'm not convinced that's going to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring is able to convert `classpath:...` values into `java.net.URL` implicitly:

```
public class Foo {
    private URL url;
    ...
}
```

.

```
<bean class = "Foo">
    <property name = "url" value = "classpath:..." />
</bean>
```

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value "classpath:etc/warmup.xml" from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'java.net.URL'; nested exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath

Comment: @IttayD: Works fine for me in Spring 3.0.2. Note that path must point to the existing resource.

Comment: I have spring 3.0.4. I looked at the source code of spring and can't see where it handled "classpath:" urls any different. From what I see it trivially tries to convert to URL. I couldn't find any URLStreamHandler implementation for "classpath"

Comment: @IttayD: Spring uses `PropertyEditor`'s for converting property values. `classpath:` to `URL` conversion is handled by [`URLEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/URLEditor.html)

Answer (score 5):

Following on from axtavt's answer, if you will allow yourself Spring annotations in the bean, you can do it like this:

```
@Value("classpath:myClasspathLocation") private URL url;
```

Answer (score 2):

create your own implementation of a spring resource by extending the org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource like MyClasspathResource extends ClassPathResource and inject this type into your bean. Like this you do not have any dependency to spring and can later reimplement your resource with something else.

```
<bean class="myBean">
 <property name="classPathType">
  <bean class="org.test.bla.MyClasspathResource">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="classpath:/org/test/bla/MyUrl" />
  </bean>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is hardly anything non-spring that's equivalent to [Spring's resource concept](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html).

You could for example use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [InputSupplier](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/InputSupplier.html) as an alternative, but you are missing powerful standard spring features if you do.