# Injecting a classpath resource into a Spring 3 bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

There is a property of type [Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) in my Spring 3 bean that should be injected with a reference to a file in the classpath. I use the @Value annotation as below to hopefully achieve this.

```
public class TestBean
{
    @Value("classpath:/abc/student/test.sql")
    private Resource SqlFile;
    ...
}
```

But the property is always null. I have confirmed that the sql file has been deployed in the maven target directory (it is at target/classes/abc/student/test.sql).

The closest solutions that I could google were [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578402/spring-inject-url-for-classpath-resource) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734671/read-file-in-classpath) which detail the xml way whereas I am interested in doing this using annotations.

Appreciate any pointers on what could be wrong here.

Thanks,

Vijay

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If it's going to be hard-coded like that, then just

```
private Resource sqlFile = new ClassPathResource("/abc/student/test.sql");
```

Otherwise, what you're really after is

```
@Value("${some.property}")
private Resource sqlFile;
```

and I believe that in injecting the property value, the correct PropertyEditor will be applied.

Comment: Agreed - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392406/populate-spring-beans-file-field-via-annotation/6392724#6392724

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Both the solutions worked. I preferred the @Value approach as it permits no dependency on Spring classes from my code.

Comment: You do know that @Value is a spring class?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to specify a property then this should work

```
@Value("${:classpath:json/inventory.json}")
Resource inventory;
```