# java spring dependency injection class path

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I don't understand why classpath is not working in my code. I'm trying to initialise MatFileReader with the external file resource.

```
<bean id="contents" class="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" factory-method="toString">
  <constructor-arg 
value="classpath:data/nps/power_spectrum/input.mat" 
type="java.io.InputStream" />
</bean>
<bean id="matInput" class="com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader">
  <constructor-arg 
name="fileName" 
value="classpath:data/nps/power_spectrum/input.mat" />
</bean>
```

classpath is working with the first bean (id=contents). I can read the contents of input.mat file. But, in the second beans (id=matInput). I got `FileNotFoundException`. It looks like compiler failed to replace the keyword `classpath`. The constructor of MatFileReader takes String as a parameter. If I use the absolute path instead of `classpath`, it works. But, I want to use the `classpath`, how can I fix it?

Comment: Is ur bean id is `id="matInput"` or `id=matinput` ?

Comment: sorry, It is "matInput". But, still having FileNotFoundException

Comment: Have you tried to replace `value="classpath:data/nps/power_spectrum/input.mat"` with `value="classpath:/data/nps/power_spectrum/input.mat"` ? or use `index=0` insetead of `name='fileName'` ?

Comment: I've tried both ways, still doesn't work. The thing that makes me confuse is, the first bean with id="contents" is working with the same URI. I can read the contents of that .mat file. But, that MatFileReader take fileName as String.

Comment: Have a look at my answer & give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor of MatFileReader takes a String as parameter, i'm not sure that "classpath:" will be kept.
You should only put :

```
<constructor-arg name="fileName" value="data/nps/power_spectrum/input.mat" />
```

And then, when you try to initialize your File, you have to make something like that :

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource(filename)
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Or

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

The last solution will be to declare filename not as a String but as a Resource.
depends on what you need

what you do is working, and the injection is good. If i understand correctly it's more a Java problem. Cause you can't initialize a file with

```
File f = new File("classpath:input.mat");
```

You have to choose one of the preceding solution i give.

Hope this help

Comment: Previously I initialise MatFileReader just like you mentioned. It works. But, I'm trying to understand Spring dependency injection and I want to inject dependency automatically when I call the bean (id="matInput").

Comment: i edit my solution, i think it's more a Java problem than a Spring problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClassPathResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) to read resources on classpath.

```
<bean id="tagProviderResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg value="/htmlcleaner.xml" />
</bean>

<util:property-path id="tagProviderFile" path="tagProviderResource.file" />

<bean id="tagProvider" class="org.htmlcleaner.ConfigFileTagProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="tagProviderFile" />
</bean>
```

More details on above code is obtained [Injecting a File From the Classpath Into a Bean](http://springinpractice.com/2012/05/12/injecting-a-file-from-the-classpath-into-a-bean).

Have a look at [Inject URL for classpath resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578402/spring-inject-url-for-classpath-resource)